# Rows and Columns layout in Android Widget

Tags: android, layout, android-layout, android-gridview, android-linearlayout

Things are simple, I want to make a widget with 4 lines and 4 rows in it, on each cell there would be a click-able image and an action set by the user via the Settings page.

The layout is like this:

[image]

What layout element is recommended to be used for this scenario ? Should I use a GridView, TableLayout, more Linearlayouts ? Keep in mind that the spacing between items must be the same. I want to make it as light as possible. So, what layout ?

> If I decide to use a GridView do you have any simple tutorial about
>   this? I can't manage to find a way of accessing the GridView from
>   AppWidgetProvider and set it's Adapter. Thank you.

LE: It seems that GridView is supported starting from Android 3.0.. please correct me if I'm wrong. In this case the only remaining thing to do is add 16 images and for each image add a onClickListener ? Brrr...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a GridView then half of your work is done for you - The only layout and formatting elements you need to consider are on a Global (GridView) and Item level.

Using a GridView will also give your Scrolling functionality and the ability to change your row/columns count based on your device (4x4 on tablet, perhaps 2x8 on a phone).

Creating an extension of BaseAdapter to attach the Grid's children will also give you the flexibility to check items, multi select and will allow you to quickly modify the implementation in future by adding and removing items at will.

If this is simply a 4x4 grid which will always ALWAYS remain the same independent of device and each "Item" will always be the same, Use a `RelativeLayout` as it will be the most lightweight and efficient ViewGroup.

Comment: GridView sounds the best alternative for my situation. I have two issues with it: how do I set its Adapter on AppWidgetProvider and how do I set setOnItemClickListener ?

Comment: No idea what AppWidgetProvider is, but the onItemClickListener is pretty basic, http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html

Comment: Ah... it seems that "Android 3.0 introduces App Widgets with collections. " and GridView is in this... si I guess no GridView for me... back to the basics.. layouts and layouts...

Comment: with your question about the click listener, you need to use the RemoteViews setOnClickPendingIntent method to set a PendingIntent for the particular event.

Comment: @Alin GridView is available in API version 1. Are you saying this is for a Widget and GridView is not supported in Widgets? Seems... wrong.

Comment: Just read your question and noticed the "I want to make a widget" :)

Comment: This is what I undrestood from: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html section Using App Widgets with Collections.. yes, for Widget building

Comment: Looks possible http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout